# Snowflake : Insert output value of UDF into another table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have created a snowflake function which generates an ID based on input.
I need to insert that output value from that function to another table.
Something like below.

```
INSERT into AA.BB.REF 
select Name ,AA.BB.UDF(str_value) 
from (select distinct ID from AA.BB.CC)
```

When I try to execute above, I get "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluate" error

Comment: Hi - your query doesn’t appear to make sense. You’re creating a dataset that only has Id in it and then selecting Name and str_value from it. Please provide the actual query you are running. Also, you’ll probably need to provide the code for the UDF as the issue may be with that rather that the query

Comment: There are several languages for UDFs. Since the only one that will generate that error is SQL, we can address that. A SQL UDF does not allow SQL that would not be supported outside a UDF. In other words, it's not encapsulated. If you take the SQL out of the UDF and try to run it along with the SQL statement that's calling it, you'll get the same error. You will need to find a way to get the UDF SQL body to work with the SQL that's going to call it.